# Flatten data frame and shift rows to columns

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have a data frame like so:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 1, 2, 2), 
  V1 = c(1:4), 
  V2 = c(5:8), 
  V3 = c(9:12))
```

Printed to the console it looks like this:

```
#   id V1 V2 V3
# 1  1  1  5  9
# 2  1  2  6 10
# 3  2  3  7 11
# 4  2  4  8 12
```

Now, I would like to transform it to this shape:

```
#   id V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
# 1  1  1  5  9  2  6 10
# 2  2  3  7 11  4  8 12
```

How can I do this with base R or the `tidyverse`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base R:

```
lists <- Map(function(x) data.frame(c(x[1,], x[2,-1])), split(df, df$id))
df2   <- do.call(rbind, lists)
```

To change the column names:

```
colnames(df2) <- c("id", paste0("V", seq_along(df2[-1])))
```

And the result:

```
# > df2
#   id V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
# 1  1  1  5  9  2  6 10
# 2  2  3  7 11  4  8 12
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with e.g. using `by`.

```
df2 <- do.call(rbind,
  by(df, df$id, function(x) c(x[1, "id"], as.vector(t(x[names(x) != "id"]))))
  )

colnames(df2) <- c("id", paste0("V", seq(ncol(df2)-1)))

  id V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1  1  1  5  9  2  6 10
2  2  3  7 11  4  8 12
```

Answer (score 2):

a possible `tidyverse` solution

```
wide <- df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(obs = row_number()) %>%
  gather(var, val, V1:V3) %>%
  unite(comb, obs, var) %>%
  spread(comb, val)

colnames(wide)[-1] <- paste("V", seq(1,ncol(wide) -1), sep = "")

# A tibble: 2 x 7
# Groups:   id [2]
#     id    V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6
#1     1     1     5     9     2     6    10
#2     2     3     7    11     4     8    12
```